# WebDriver/Mocha Promise not returning what I expect

Tags: selenium, webdriver, promise, mocha.js

I've started to play with Web Driver and Mocha to learn testing but I'm running into a few roadblocks. When returning the promise from

```
driver.findElement(By.id('promo'))
.then(element => console.log(element))
```

I get a WebElement object that really isn't the resolved promise I want. The web element object being { Object {driver_, id_} }.
I can't really find any documentation that would help me understand how Web Driver works with JavaScript and Mocha.

I ran this test just to return the promise and it was the only one that returns an expected result

```
it('has the correct title', function(done) {
  driver.get('http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/')
   .then(() => driver.getTitle())
   .then(title => console.log(title))
   .then(() => done())
   .catch(error => done(error));
});
```

This returns 'Selenium WebDriver' which is the result I expect that I can make assertions on. However any other function I try either isn't a function or returns a Web Element object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly how WebDriver works. When you ask it to find an element in the page, it sends a query to the browser for the DOM element. But the DOM element cannot be passed over to your script as-is. Consider that your Selenium script is usually running in an entirely different memory space (here, Node.js) than the DOM objects (the browser being controlled by Selenium).

What Selenium does is give you a *representation* of the DOM object: a `WebElement`. When you dump this to the console in Node.js, you get only the representation that Selenium creates, not the DOM object. The representation contains an internal id (not to be confused with a CSS id) that allows Selenium to relate it to the DOM object, and it has some bookkeeping information but you won't see anything that matches what you see if you do a `console.log` on the browser side with a DOM element: you won't see `parentNode`, `childNodes`, `innerHTML`, etc.

You need to use the methods on [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html) in order inspect and manipulate the corresponding DOM object. Or you can pass it to [`executeScript`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html#executeScript) if you need to do something that Selenium won't allow you to do easily. `executeScript` will automatically convert the `WebElement` to a DOM element on the browser side.

Comment: How exactly do I use the methods from WebElement to inspect and manipulate the DOM Object? What ever I try I usually get _**(method)** is not a function._ Can I get an example?